# Python logging for non-trivial uses?

Tags: python, logging

I'm attempting to use the python logging module to do complex things.  I'll leave the motivation for this design out because it would greatly lengthen the post, but I need to have a root logger that spams a regular log file for our code and libraries that use logging --  and a collection of other loggers that go to *different* log files.

The overall setup should look like this.  I will do everything to stdout in this example to simplify the code.

```
import logging, sys
root = logging.getLogger('')
top = logging.getLogger('top')
bottom = logging.getLogger('top.bottom')

class KillFilter(object):
    def filter(self, msg):
        return 0

root_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
top_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
bottom_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('ROOT'))
top_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('TOP HANDLER'))
bottom_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("BOTTOM HANDLER"))

msg_killer = KillFilter()

root.addHandler(root_handler)
top.addHandler(top_handler)
bottom.addHandler(bottom_handler)

top.addFilter(msg_killer)

root.error('hi')
top.error('hi')
bottom.error('hi')
```

This outputs

```
ROOT
BOTTOM HANDLER
ROOT
```

The second root handler call should not because according to logging documentation the `msg_killer` will stop the message from going up to the root logger.  Obviously the documentation could use improvement.

Edit: removed my "in the moment" harsh words for python logging.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, I get a different output on my machine (running Python 2.6):

```
ROOT
BOTTOM HANDLER
TOP HANDLER
ROOT
```

Filtering is only applied on the logger that the message is issued to, and if it passes the filters, it's then propagated to all the handlers of the parent loggers (and not the loggers themselves) - I don't know the rationale for this decision. If you want to stop propagation at say the "top" Logger instance, set:

```
top.propagation = False
```

Comment: Correct command is `top.propagate = False` instead of propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Source is messed with different case identifiers, more useful version:

```
import logging, sys
root = logging.getLogger('')
level1 = logging.getLogger('level1')
level2 = logging.getLogger('level1.level2')

class KillFilter(object):
    def filter(self, msg):
        return 0

root_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
top_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
bottom_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
root_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('ROOT HANDLER - %(msg)s'))
top_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('level1 HANDLER - %(msg)s'))
bottom_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('level2 HANDLER - %(msg)s'))

msg_killer = KillFilter()

root.addHandler(root_handler)
level1.addHandler(top_handler)
level2.addHandler(bottom_handler)

level1.addFilter(msg_killer)
level1.propagate = False

root.error('root_message')
level1.error('level1_message')
level2.error('level2_message')
```